# Secondary axis tick marks missing when choosing "resolve": {"scale": {"x": "shared"}}

Tags: axis, vega-lite

I am trying to make secondary axis where times will be shown and after to replace with some names, but this times should be connected so I cannot use "independent" in "resolve". So I am using "shared", but this time there is no tick marks is showing at the top of chart. But when selecting "independent" it is showing. Is there any solution for this behavior?

This is code in vega editor, [Timeline Graph](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega-lite/N4IgJghgLhIFygG4QDYFcCmBneBtUscIA6hmADQAEADAJyUCCaA5pQEzVsDMNAbHNWoDqlAOIBZACohyIAEbwSZKnUYt2nHgEYA7MLjcxUmSADGihlpNhFAISuysMAE5QA+lACWAWwyKAytBUXCIAIhimlFoAHLT01PyCwkbSsqHQfkSkFDT0TKwc3CAAvuQEitkqeeqF2kJJgikmClnKuWoFmlHRAmxwXFpNsuZEDGzWduOOLu5evgFBlCGU4ZExcVEALPqNEqkg6VCZSjmq+RpFpeWtp9Wdhlq0AloCOkPyFW1nNV1sfdQvXTvEYgSwTIi2KYgJwQVweHzHQJQYJhCLdDZ-HYiPYmQ7HSrtc61EoAXVKIAwADtTAB7MCeSnMeCgACezJAADNPBgUDYiOZZFAWQAHY405z0ymoExeKAoTKUtAoFCyCAAD08OAQIBQEDkPIAwjSUOLFHJdaYANYlYrk3UsjDOPCgYWwiDeLX4EBS+ZEAAWnmYfpQgb9UBMWB5EXD2qFosUwppDPDshplMU3hpaEjNMQjptZW97uOzGcnhsjijphjIGTjuQKGaDL50NMqGwJULPrFws8tO8wojVZjoDjx0TyZMXJ5YE94BAZNkcmbinlzCpNmKJNk3lh1tjIuOclhEagzhplqPFut5KptMlTO1avZ095ilggsPiiOA-F0tVGpaqAur6igACiarCk6RCQFAaDeAAdCBPImMhKBGia0HyNeJiluW8Bnpgsh4WA6RYH6eAAKwIZR24gCRGGmkQpYYGysgAF7Nhgz5wFo5KyvKiiSAiAD0oRoM40CeGmnYgGq4zaq+LYKOStKYS+3JvjBEZtoJ2pgDSu4MngID2CYkILrIkmMpkuAgAAxAAYo5Oi0IIJj2ToDC2NE7mLjqGDrpSfKjp4crHGqkURiy3hyMa-hnheGCMVhABySqNo4MVxSgkhfkQWAAI5oLCfiyGhAAyPhhfAWgcLa0znpexDllAFHarSwVhdJ6ZwF6rqSd4igBkGIZBimFIDkK8AcqgkayA2mC1VuC2oEtAjkjSrqmGFbIdWm9JeDJfWjtgI6cppLZuG4kbytWZDXSYGDFdKRA0hyHKyYtmTUDRVwgAN7qKFtfaGYOq3oJkfF0d98C-ZRtr-WeECUlgHLikNJ0gHMGAAKqUjVRAOrCmaUm1sEYH6WbOFg3gMmgRxYJGnWzlOl2KDCcI4yYEBauAGTc-9ummEqGSKBTOMABTE84kuwfBCF4gAlFQpNtXL0AK8rVAUxrcGIdrlBUxJWB6wrnOzAiKuUHTiqM2biEW-CvjW8zB2m-LjszM7GBK0rPN85SGAAO7CfMK0gLuzj7qO+XY321qNUlZo4be1J0gyj6gDxoBKYoQehwiMpxz+iaSZlIDqpq7JoRBUHi5riFoaheqGsaTHYRAVq4WWfKERgxG92R7W4NRtEcVxPF8fxNLGl4g5Y3nRAF2HZXx+FihgXmZOUAlsJQJQq-F-GRCl3+Ffo84u41gApGAAC0N9yI-LKUDfAAScA3+IX-+KStp0WcNgY0eZ2RYF0pkbOiguKimClScMDUzBpi5FnSugF2QCWSu3LC5ou43ltEAA) so now x axis is in independent state and secondary axis displaying but not connected with main axis, when I am switching it to "shared" it is considering only axis at the bottom I guess, at the top ticks disappearing.